# Mocking dynamic finder in grails unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I am using grails 1.3.7.

While writing the unit tests for my controller, I am getting errors as my action in the controller uses dynamic finder for example "findByName('ABC')".
I understand that I need to mock the dynamic finders as well and I tried that thing out.But unfortunately didnt work out.
I request you to please help me out with the exact mocking snippet I need to use.
Also, for all thses kinds of mocking things, please suggest some documentaion URLs which will have all these.

Also, In my grails app, I have associataion between three domains as "hasMany and belongsTo". So while writing unit tests for controllers, please suggest how exactly I need to mock these domain classes.

Please I request all of you to answer asap as I am stuck with these doubts.
Thanks in Advance,
and awaiting for positive answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If `name` is a property of the domain, then the dynamic finders will "automatically" be mocked when you [mock the domain](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing).  You should simply be able to do:

```
mockDomain(YourDomain)
```

At this point you will just have null returned, so create some instances if you want that query to return them:

```
YourDomain instance = new YourDomain(name: 'foo')
mockDomain(YourDomain, [instance])
```

then you can do:

```
assert instance == YourDomain.findByName('foo')
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone got an update for this question with Grails 4.0.0 and Spock? Because it doesn't seem to have working dynamic finders.

Answer (score 0):

To mock a domain dynamic finder try:

```
def someDomainMock = new GrailsMock(SomeDomain)
someDomainMock.demand.static.findByName(1..1) { String name ->
    [new SomeDomain(name: name + '_1'), new SomeDomain(name: name + '_2')]
}
```